# PHP page does not redirect after login completed

Tags: php, sql, session, http-redirect

My php would not redirect after has login I don't see why 
loog this its my login page

http://transylvanyanorthampton.com/main_login.php

username abcd

password  12345678

```
$header('Location: http://transylvanyanorthampton.com/login_success.php');
```

any other ideea cause I am stuck my checkloging php its this

```html
<?php

$host = "localhost"; // Host name 
$username = "abcd"; // Mysql username 
$password = "******"; // Mysql password 
$db_name = "abcd"; // Database name 
$tbl_name = "members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$username=$_POST['username']; 
$password=$_POST['password']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($password);
$sqli="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysqli_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$session_("username")="username";
$session_("password")="password"; 
header('Location: http://transylvanyanorthampton.com/login_success.php');
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

Comment: You're mixing mysql_ and mysqli_. That doesn't work.

Comment: and what in the world is `$session_("username")`?

Comment: a user gave me that cause it wood not log in what so ever and if i use mysqli_select_db  will not connect to the database for unknown reason

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: i have try it it das not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New session variables are set with `$_SESSION['key'] = 'value';`. Also don't forget to start the session with `session_start();` before creating sessions.

Also your code may be working if you change all `mysqli_` to `mysql_`. Combining `mysql` and `mysqli` won't work'; and your code looks more like a `mysql`-concept.

However, instead of changing `mysqli` to `mysql`, I'd recommend you to make yourself more familiar with `mysqli` and use that for your database requests, as `mysql` is deprecated.

Comment: steal nothing move everything from mysql to mysqli but steal wont work any other idea ?